ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib' python
I am doing a school assignment with Python where I am trying to generate a bar chart where each bar represents the sales of a specific month in the years 2021 and 2022.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

meses = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho']
vendas_2021 = [150, 200, 220, 210, 240, 230]
vendas_2022 = [180, 210, 235, 205, 250, 245]

x = np.arange(len(meses)) 
largura = 0.35  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - largura/2, vendas_2021, largura, label='2021', color='blue')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + largura/2, vendas_2022, largura, label='2022', color='green')

ax.set_xlabel('Meses')
ax.set_ylabel('Vendas')
ax.set_title('Vendas por mês nos anos 2021 e 2022')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(meses)
ax.legend()

def autolabel(rects):
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.annotate('{}'.format(height),
                    xy=(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2, height),
                    xytext=(0, 3), 
                    textcoords="offset points",
                    ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()`

When compiling I get an error:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'


have you installed matplotlib?

have you tried from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

first check by removing the single quotes that cover the entire code.
The error you get is because the Matplotlib library is not installed in your Python environment. To solve this problem, you will need to install Matplotlib. To do this, open your terminal or command console and type:
pip install matplotlib

